# Translating 既にニュースにもなっているが昨夜７時頃、会長の大栗さんがテニススクールの帰り道に夕摩川河川敷で河原にあった岩で殴り殺された事件だ

Tags: translation, syntax

So I am currently trying to translate a sentence from Japanese to English, but it's quite long and I'm having issues with how to optimally put it, without it being too messy or without losing too much information.

> 既にニュースにもなっているが昨夜７時頃、会長の大栗さんがテニススクールの帰り道に[夕摩川]{ゆうまがわ}河川敷で河原にあった岩で殴り殺された事件だ。

Here's my attempt at translating it:

> It's even made the news but, yesterday evening, around 7 o'clock, the
> president Ooguri was found beaten to death with a rock, on the dry bed
> of the river in the Yuumagawa flood plain, on his way back from tennis
> school.

There are a few things I'm not sure of

1- The sentence originally ends with 「事件だ」but I didn't find a way to plug it in my sentence. It looks like a subordinate clause to me but I'm not sure.

2- I put "Yuumagawa flood plain" for 「夕摩川河川敷」assuming Yuumagawa is a name, but I found nothing about it.

Comment: Also, 河川敷 doesn't really mean "dry river bed" the way we would think about it in English. It's a raised and flattened riverbank like you can see here: https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E6%B2%B3%E5%B7%9D%E6%95%B7&espv=2&biw=1248&bih=669&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz9a_Ot8_QAhVEHpQKHf2NCpgQ_AUIBygC

Answer (score 1):

1. I think this phrase "it is the case that" may be placed before "yesterday evening" like "it is the case that yesterday evening, around 7 o'clock, the president Ooguri was found".
2. It may be a imaginary river, though 多摩川{たまがわ} is a real river in Tokyo.

Answer (score -1):

It is already broadcast in news, but around 7 o’clock last night, there was an incident wherein the committee chairman Mr. oguri was found beaten and killed by a rock that was on the riverbank at Yumagawa on his way back to the tennis school.？？